# golang what is import side effect

Tags: go

```
import (
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
    _ "image/png"
    ...
)
```

In [effective go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#blank_import) it says that these kinds of imports mean side effect. I've read several SO answers but none explain what is an `import side effect`. Could someone elaborate the term `import side effect`?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

When they say 'import side effects' they are essentially referring to code/features that are used statically. Meaning just the import of the package will cause some code to execute on app start putting my system in a state different than it would be without having imported that package (like code in an `init()` which in their example registers handlers, it could also lay down config files, modify resource on disc, ect). The effective go tutorial is explaining this simply to illustrate reasons why a developer might want to do a blank import ie; `import _ "somepackageImNotUsingReally"`

EDIT: to add additional context when I said `init()` I was referring to this method; https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#init - any imported packages will have their init methods called prior to main being called. Whatever is in the `init()` is a side effect. I don't think there can be any others because things like constants will be at the package scope, not the global scope so it wouldn't redefine constants or anything like that.

EDIT2: as pointed out in comments and explained in the init link above " is called after all the variable declarations in the package have evaluated their initializers" meaning code like `PackageScopeVar := unexportedInitializerThatWritesToDisc()` will run and could have side effects.

Comment: Still doesn't explain how this [lib/pq init()](https://github.com/lib/pq/blob/b269bd035a727d6c1081f76e7a239a1b00674c40/conn.go) works. It only calls `sql.Register("postgres", &drv{})`. How does all the other codes effect?

Comment: @Entei yes it does... Firstly, I explained what an import side effect is, not the side effect of that specific import. If you'd like to know the specific side effect of that then look at the docs for `sql.Register` http://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Register ... if you call that method again in some other scope it will panic. That effects all the code.

Comment: "It only calls sql.Register("postgres", &drv{})" **is** the desired side effect: The packages registers itself to be known in package sql.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal, don't forget, in addition to `init` a package can do something like `var foo = someOtherFunction()` as a package variable which will call the function (and have side effects) before `init` even runs. E.g. `var _ = os.Remove("somefile")`

Comment: @DaveC yeah, I suppose that should be included in the answer though reading the 1 paragraph blurb on `init` explains the order in which things happen.

Comment: @Volker Am I missing something? The "desired side effect" is only one function with empty drv{}. How does all the other code get executed with this side effect since there is no connection between them as I could observe.

Comment: @Entei do you think the author wrote that single, very explicit, line of code by accident? I don't get what you're questioning. It is the intended side effect of the packages author. You haven't stated how it interacts with your project but it sounds like it's a problem which probably means you should look for a different package. Are you familiar with the implementation of `Register` and what it does? I personally am not but that is the code that executes, follow it's source if you want to know all that happens. Everything is explicit, there isn't any other code running.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal are you saying importing a 5k line project's all effect is simply one function? I am questioning the effect we are seeing by importing lib/pq. Is the effect just init function or are there other effects which I can not see?

Comment: @Entei the init function is the main thing that happens. A few others do too, like these statements are evaluated; https://github.com/lib/pq/blob/b269bd035a727d6c1081f76e7a239a1b00674c40/conn.go#L30 but I don't see that having any noticeable 'side effect' since they're in the packages scope. Is that the only effect of importing the package? No. It's the only side effect. You import the package to make use of it's types and/or methods. This is a side effect of importing it and it is the only one who's effect isn't encapsulated.

Comment: @Entei Yes you are completely missing how important registering the pq driver with package sql is. It simply would not work if it wouldn't be registered. Take a look at how package image and e.g. image/png interact. It is the same mechanism. And no: No other code is directly executed by the import statement alone. This happens afterwards.

Comment: @Volker besides init(), does heap variables count as side effect? Does heap const and interfaces also count as side effect? The OP only specified init() function as side effect nothing else.

Comment: What are "heap variables" in Go? Some things are place on the heap, some not; this decision even depends on the compiler version used. Even stranger: what are "heap consts"? And what do you mean when you say "Do[...] interfaces also count as side effect?" Interfaces are types... May I ask why you are so interested in side effects of imported packages?