# How do I load dylib sqlite3 extensions in golang?

Tags: sqlite, go

I need to load sqlite3 extensions (dylib) into a go program.
Either statically or dynamic, any option is fine.
The extension I am trying to install is https://github.com/asg017/sqlite-vss
I have never used sqlite3 before, nor loading extensions and am fairly new to go.

I tried db.Exec(".load", ".vector0") where vector0 is a filename of the dylib.
This does not work, as `.` is not recognised.

I also tried doing go get -u github.com/asg017/sqlite-vss/bindings/go with my vss0 and vector0 dylib files in my directory, and following the documentation to the best of my ability.
This results in a sqlite_vector0 not found error.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [`sqlite-vss` with `go`](https://alexgarcia.xyz/sqlite-vss/go.html) and [the `go` binding's `README.md`](https://github.com/asg017/sqlite-vss/tree/main/bindings/go#readme). You need to do a [side-effects import](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32465526/6611700) and add some `LDFLAGS` (you can [read up more here](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/cgo)).

Taking the example from the `README.md`:

```golang
package main

import (
    "database/sql"

    _ "github.com/asg017/sqlite-vss/bindings/go"
    _ "github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3"
)

// #cgo LDFLAGS: -Lpath/to/sqlite-vss-libs/ -Wl,-undefined,dynamic_lookup
import "C"

func main() {
  /* */
}
```

(make sure to provide the correct value for `path/to/sqlite-vss-libs`)